# Detect URL changes (without window unload)

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, google-chrome-extension

I want to add a listener to "before URL change" event, with access to the old URL. `window.onbeforeunload` does not fire if the page does not reload (AJAX driven pages).

This happens on YouTube video pages, when you click on another video in the right navigation column, for example.

I have read [this post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1520-Binding-Events-To-Non-DOM-Objects-With-jQuery.htm), which polls `window.location`. But this does not capture the old URL.

This is for a Chrome extension. I'm looking for a way to detect before URL change in javascript.

Comment: Give the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.history) a shot.

Comment: try searching for local storage

Comment: You might be looking for the `beforeunload` event coupled with the History API

Comment: You want to use this in a popup window? Or using a greesemonkey script? Your missing some key information in your post.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I'm programming a chrome extension. Is there an alternative for Chrome?

Comment: @meewoK I'm programming in chrome extension, but I'm looking for a generic way to do this in javascript in Chrome. I hope to execute some functions whenever a new flash video is loaded. The beforeunload does not fire for some cases, where url changes without a page reload.

Comment: You've specifically said that you want to detect navigation on YouTube. In that case, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18398921/938089) to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397962/chrome-extension-is-not-loading-on-browser-navigation-at-youtube "Chrome extension is not loading on browser navigation at YouTube").

Answer (score 4):

For AJAX-driven pages that use the `history` API (most of them, including YouTube), you can splice into `history.pushState`.

For Chrome, the old url will be in the `spf-referer` property.  (Also, the `location.href` will still be set to the old URL while pushState is firing, too.)

So code like this will work:

```
var H               = window.history;
var oldPushState    = H.pushState;
H.pushState         = function (state) {
    if (typeof H.onpushstate == "function") {
        H.onpushstate ({state: state} );
    }
    return oldPushState.apply (H, arguments);
}
window.onpopstate = history.onpushstate = function (evt) {
    console.log ("Old URL: ", evt.state["spf-referer"]);
}
```

Note that, because you need to override the target page's `pushState` function, you must [inject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/331508) this code from your content script.

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing a Chrome extension, you can listen to the `onUpdated` event which is fired when a tab url is changed. More information here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated.

Comment: I am aware of the tab onUpdate. However, you can only detect with background script, when the url is updated. I'm looking for a way to detect in content script, while still having access to the old url.

Comment: Then you can use the method of polling `window.location` as mentioned in your question. For having access to the old url, just save it as a global variable, or save it to localStorage. Youtube uses History API, so it'll not reload your content script when navigating to another video.