# How to run a script every time a new page is loaded on YouTube?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, greasemonkey

Since some time last year, YouTube made it so that every page is not actually loading an entirely new page, but primarily just re-loading the contents in `div#content`. You can notice this when you click on a link in YouTube and see the red loading bar at the top of the page.

I have a Greasemonkey script that modified elements on YouTube, but now that YouTube doesn't reload the entire page, the Greasemonkey script no longer fires on every "new" page. How can I make the Greasemonkey script fire on every "new" page that I load on YouTube?

I'm using jQuery in this Greasemonkey script. I tried using functions like `.on()` with `DOMNodeInserted` but I can't find the right combination to make it work properly. With the event listeners that I've been using, I end up running my script hundreds of times for each page load, such as with the following:

`$('div#page').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'div#content', function() { });`

Another solution I was thinking of was making all links on YouTube load pages like normal, without the new way that they are doing it.

Comment: attach an eventlistener to the div#content.

Comment: @Mike: That's a decent answer, if you provide a short code sample

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for some sample code. I know I need an event listener, but I can't find the right "combination" to get it working properly on YouTube specifically. I've done it before on other sites, but YouTube is a bit different it seems.

Comment: There is no change event for div's, so your best solution seems to be using Intervals to check to see if the content has changed.

[Here's some code someone else wrote, I'm not reinventing the wheel on this one.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3234646/3116761)

Comment: Would it also be possible to just watch for a url change? possibly something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161906/handle-url-anchor-change-event-in-js

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't this script work with successive page clicks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949888/why-doesnt-this-script-work-with-successive-page-clicks)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. I've found a solution to my own question, and posted it. I think my solution is actually applicable to a wider range of problems related to writing Greasemonkey (and similar) YouTube scripts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out myself after some research. First off, I don't like solutions that use `setTimeout`. This is often one method suggested in favor over the deprecated `DOMNodeInserted` for instance (which I use in some of my scripts, but try to avoid as much as possible), but if possible, I always prefer a solution where the script actually executes after a specific event. I've posted the solution I initially used in the first section below, then the final solution I used in the second section. **All code below requires jQuery.**

## Decent solution, but not the best

At first, I had a solution where I added a `click` event to all `A` elements, which would run a timer that ran my script after 2 seconds. This isn't elegant, because if the page loads quickly, then there's a split second where the script hasn't run. And if the page loads for more than two seconds, then the script doesn't run at all. Script below:

```
$('a').click(function()
{
    setTimeout(youtubeFunction, 2000);
});
```

## Much better solution

So I began looking for a solution that was related to what I wanted to accomplish. I eventually found other people with a similar problem to mine (such as people wanting to create a Chrome script that modifies YouTube pages). This led me to [this particular Stack Overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18398921/420217), which basically says that the red loading bar at the top of YouTube pages was a CSS transition element, and that it created a `transitionend` (case sensitive) event when it was finished. The code in the linked solution wasn't complete (for me anyway), but it did explain how to achieve a working solution. The code I have runs only once per page, which is perfect. So here's what I have now:

```
function youtubePageChange()
{
    youtubeFunction();
    $('body').on('transitionend', function(event)
    {
        if (event.target.id != 'progress') return false;
        youtubeFunction();
    });
}

$(youtubePageChange);
```

To explain the code above, basically I run the code once for when you first load a YouTube page (such as by typing the URL in the address bar). Then for every subsequent click that requires the progress bar, the code runs again.

## Red progress bar code

Oh, and for future reference, when the red progress bar appears at the top of YouTube pages, the site temporarily adds a new `DIV` to the end of `BODY`, with the following code:

```
<div id="progress" class="waiting" style="transition-duration: 400ms; width: 99%;"><dt></dt><dd></dd></div>
```

Comment: I'm having problems with this now. It only works half the time. YouTube must've changed something and I can't pinpoint what it is at the moment. I've just reverted back to `setInterval` for now, as a fallback.

Comment: Same here.  Works most of the time, but not all the time

Answer (score 1):

You can set a listener which gets called when the page has finished loading.

This is for the new YouTube material design:

```
body.addEventListener("yt-navigate-finish", function() {
    //your code
});
```

And this for the old:

```html
window.addEventListener("spfdone", function() {
    //your code
});
```

(if you are using *monkey, you'll need to use `unsafeWindow`)

Keep in mind that the old design will be discontinued, so your script may not work after that.

Answer (score 0):

Hooking into the popstate might be an option, but i was unable to make that work correctly for some reason (youtube may be preventing it from propagating), so i came up with this that shows the concept:

```
var currentState = "";
setInterval(function(){
    if (currentState != history.state["spf-referer"]) {
        currentState = history.state["spf-referer"];
        console.log("Do Stuff!");
    }
},250)
```

Just watches for the history.state to change, at which point it will log. The state should change any time the url changes, even if it wasn't due to a page reload.

Comment: Could I do something like use the `hashchange` event? Although I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work, but perhaps something like that might do the trick.

Comment: No, because the hash isn't changing. The correct event is the popState event, but like i said i can't get that to work with youtube. They're likely stopping it.

Comment: This is heavy on memory, when the user watches a long video. A video for an hour would produce 14400 loop waste checks.