# How to get grease monkey to run on Youtube link changes?

Tags: javascript, youtube, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

It's my first time using grease monkey, and I'm a novice at javascript, but I have some simple code to delete the suggested videos on the right-hand side of YouTube, which I find can distract me from work:

`var elem = document.getElementById('watch-related');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);`

I've tried using `addEventListener()`; as well as a `while` loop with a `setTimeOut()`; and I've tried `setInterval()`. None worked. But they all, including the plain code, work if I refresh the page or arrive at the link from an external source, but if I arrive at the video from another YouTube page it doesn't.

I think it has something to do with the way YouTube loads pages, but I haven't been able to find any workarounds. Any ideas?

Edit: I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123035/how-to-run-a-script-every-time-a-new-page-is-loaded-on-youtube?rq=1), which has some good info on this topic, but also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Install [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/) or [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/), and add a custom filter: `youtube.com###watch-related`.

**Option 2 (in case you have to use Greasemonkey):**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Youtube Suggested Video Hider
// @include      https://www.youtube.com/watch?*
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
GM_addStyle('#watch-related { display: none; }')
```