# How do I reload a Greasemonkey script when AJAX changes the URL without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, greasemonkey

I have an application that I am trying to create a Greasemonkey script for. It utilizes a lot of jQuery and AJAX to load content dynamically.

I've noticed that the URL *does* change each time I load a new item, even though the page doesn't refresh.

Is there a listener I can place on the page to relaunch the script each time the URL changes?

Answer (score 25):

How you do this depends on the site/application and on what you are trying to do.  **Here are your options**, easiest and most robust first:

1. Don't try to catch URL changes.  [**Use calls to `waitForKeyElements()`** to act on the parts of the various pages that you wanted to manipulate in the first place.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17385193/331508)  This neatly handles a whole slew of timing issues inherent with all the other approaches.
   See also: ["Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15048223/331508).
2. [Just **poll for URL changes.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17872564/331508)  It's simple and works well in practice, with fewer timing issues than all but technique #1.
3. If the site uses AJAX that changes the *fragment* (AKA "hash"), [**fire on the `hashchange` event**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024538/331508).  Alas, fewer and fewer AJAX sites do this.
4. Use **Mutation Observers** to monitor changes **to the `<title>` tag**. *Most* AJAX pages are nice enough to change the title too.  This may fire before your target content is loaded, though.
5. [**Hack into the `history.pushState` function.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18950690/331508) This gives faster notice of page changes, BUT 95% of the time, it fires before your target elements have loaded. You will usually still need a timer. Plus, it brings in cross-scope problems, in a userscript environment.

---

For reference, **here is a polling example**. It's still the best, bare-bones, cross-browser, catch-all method:

```
/*--- Note, gmMain () will fire under all these conditions:
    1) The page initially loads or does an HTML reload (F5, etc.).
    2) The scheme, host, or port change.  These all cause the browser to
       load a fresh page.
    3) AJAX changes the URL (even if it does not trigger a new HTML load).
*/
var fireOnHashChangesToo    = true;
var pageURLCheckTimer       = setInterval (
    function () {
        if (   this.lastPathStr  !== location.pathname
            || this.lastQueryStr !== location.search
            || (fireOnHashChangesToo && this.lastHashStr !== location.hash)
        ) {
            this.lastPathStr  = location.pathname;
            this.lastQueryStr = location.search;
            this.lastHashStr  = location.hash;
            gmMain ();
        }
    }
    , 111
);

function gmMain () {
    console.log ('A "New" page has loaded.');
    // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE.
}
```

Comment: It turns out sometimes this kicks in before the page has changed, so the solution is to put whatever you do in `gmMain()` in a `setTimeout()` (I use 500 milliseconds), on top of this, when you navigate back, the function gets called again, you can find a the container of the AJAX content, and add a class to the first element, and don't do anything if this classes exists.

Answer (score -1):

"I've noticed the URL does change each time" with a lot of AJAX would lead me that they are using the History API. If that's the case, take a look at [`window.onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onpopstate). That should fire on each URL change using the History API.

Comment: greasemonkey doesnt seen to like window.onpopstate. I cant seem to bind any events to it.

Comment: @Sugitime I'm assuming you're using [`unsafeWindow`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow) and/or using `addEventListener`?

Comment: @Sugitime did you try unsafeWindow too?

Comment: [`popstate` does NOT fire in most usage of the `history` API.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14112341/331508).