# Subscribing to Angular router events from userscript

Tags: javascript, angular, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am trying to write a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script which tracks URL changes. (similar to polling approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18997637/2800764))

However, I would like to extend a bit such that if the page has Angular I would rather subscribe the routing events instead of polling. ([How to detect a route change in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular))

Is it possible to subscribe to Angular events from userscripts?

Answer (score 0):

I am working with a script that looks like it is trying to do that in this block... but doesn't seem to properly detect the route.

```
const updateTragetOnState = (state) => {
    if (state.vssNavigationState?.routeId !== "ms.vss-code-web.create-pull-request-route") {
        // only work on create-pull-request-route
        return;
    }
```

For the record, that codeblock is not my own. It is a portion of a script sample submitted by Pei-Tang Huang for the purpose of working with modifying a pull request selection in Azure Devops. And in my case, it does not work.