# Content script isn't firing on Twitch

Tags: google-chrome-extension

### The problem

This content script fires on Twitch's "choose a channel" page, but when you choose the channel, it doesn't fire. How do I make it fire on the channels page when redirected from "choose a channel" page? Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykZmP.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhWnP.png

---

### The code

*manifest.json*

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "stuff",
   "version": "1.0",
   "description": "desc",

   "content_scripts": [ 
       {
          "js": [ "script.js" ],
          "matches": [ "http://*.twitch.tv/*" ],
          "run_at": "document_end"
       }
   ]
}
```

*script.js*

```
function init()
{
    alert("Script executed");
}

init();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome extension is not loading on browser navigation at YouTube](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397962/chrome-extension-is-not-loading-on-browser-navigation-at-youtube)

Comment: Completely different questions.

Comment: It's the same reason. Just different URLs.

Comment: I've checked it with chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated and window.onpopstate. Twitch doesn't use history api.

Comment: `window.onpopstate` won't fire since, well, it's not being popped, only pushed. Please include the code you tried with `onHistoryStateUpdated`.

Comment: added `"webNavigation"` to permissions in *manifest*  
and added the following code to *bg.js*

    `chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(details) { console.log('executed'); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I have solved the problem. I'm answering my own question in case other people would need this. I've used a script called *waitForKeyElements.js* which was originally made for Greasemonkey, but apparently it can also be used in the chrome extensions. I hope this will help someone.

Question closed.

**The script:** https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891#file-waitforkeyelements-js

Comment: Yes, but _which_ element?

Comment: Also, a consider using `MutationObserver`s for performance reasons.

Comment: In this particular case that can be any element that you encounter on the channel's page, but not on "choose the channel" page. This question is actually the simplified version of an actual problem I had. I had a problem with a chat window, so in my problem's case I had to watch the ".textarea-contain" element.  
  
And nice job there Xan, you could have told me about mutation observers before...