# Chrome webNavigation.onComplete not working?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that executes some code when the user is on a youtube page with a video. As far as I can tell, my code is correct, but It isn't working.

eventPage.js:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(){
  console.log("Test")
},{url: [{pathContains: "watch", hostSuffix: "youtube.com"}]});
```

and my manifest file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "youtubeExtension",
  "description": "A chrome extension for youtube",
  "version": "0.1",

  "permissions": ["https://www.youtube.com/", "webNavigation"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistant": false
  }
}
```

It seems onCompleted doesn't work on youtube.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The event is not fired when you navigate from one video to another?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using webNavigation you can also use

Add this to your background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
    if (tab.url.indexOf("youtube.com") != -1) {
      alert("Youtube load complete");
      injectScripts();
    }

  }
});
```

and add the following to your mainfest.json

```
"permissions": ["https://www.youtube.com/", "webNavigation","tabs"]
```

This will work just as well

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You should be aware that stack snippets are really only for self contained html/css/js.  An extension is javascript, but it can't really run in a snippet, so it doesn't quite make sense to post it that way.

Comment: if you open youtube as background tab it will fire too. TS means the currently visible tab.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It was exactly what i was looking for.
@Jamshed Katta.

Answer (score 7):

[`chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCompleted) is only triggered when a document has finished loading. When you navigate to a different page on YouTube, the new page is not really "loaded" in a traditional way, but the page is dynamically updated, and the URL is replaced using `history.pushState`. To detect this kind of "navigations", use the [`chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onHistoryStateUpdated) event in addition to the `onCompleted` event.

Another way to detect videos on YouTube pages is by using content scripts on YouTube and some event specific to YouTube, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397962/chrome-extension-is-not-loading-on-browser-navigation-at-youtube/18398921#18398921).