# Chrome Extension Permissions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I have been working on a Chrome Extension that injects Javascript on Youtube video pages, but for some reason, it is also injecting the JS on the homepage and other non video pages. I read through the Google documents for building a Chrome Extension, as well as read a few other questions on here, and thought I had a good understanding of the wild card(*) but maybe not.

1. With the below permissions code snippet, shouldn't it only inject the CSS/JS on the video pages due to "watch?v=*"?
2. Is there a better way to go about detecting video pages?

```
"permissions": [
    "https://youtube.com/watch?v=*",
    "http://youtube.com/watch?v=*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://youtube.com/watch?v=*",
        "http://youtube.com/watch?v=*"
      ],
      "css": [
        "src/inject/inject.css"
      ]
    },
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://youtube.com/watch?v=*",
        "http://youtube.com/watch?v=*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "src/inject/inject.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: for the "matches", you need to add `http` without the secure `s`, I think... It could be possible that you're testing on non-secure youtube...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I added that in and updated my question post. It's still injecting CSS/JS on all pages though instead of just pages with "watch?v=*" in the URL.

Comment: I don't know why this is happening (I'm still new to Chrome extensions), but try `*://*.youtube.com/watch?v=*`. Or try replacing the `?` with `%3F`

Comment: Still no luck using "*://*.youtube.com/watch?v=*" either :( Thanks for the suggestions, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try using `%3F`? `*://*.youtube.com/watch%3Fv=*`

Comment: Yeah, just tried using that after I posted the last comment. No luck. That actually broke functionality on all pages.

Comment: Sorry then - you'll have to wait for someone else! I have no idea what isn't working. I guess, in your inject.js file you could check the URL again, but that's not a very good method seeing as this should work!

Comment: Make sure you modify the permissions as well!

Comment: Also, I don't think you can use a wildcard for query parameters, see [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns). Maybe try `*://*.youtube.com/watch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's assume the following in the manifest file. This snippet is equivalent to what you've posted in the question, but just a bit shorter, `"*://"` = http and https; You don't need to declare the permission if you inject a content script through the manifest file.

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": [ "*://youtube.com/watch?v=*" ],
  "css": [ "src/inject/inject.css" ],
  "js": [ "src/inject/inject.js" ]
}]
```

About your two questions:

> 1. shouldn't it only inject the CSS/JS on the video pages due to "watch?v=*"?

Yes, and it does. However, YouTube does not really "unload" the page when you navigate to a different page. Instead, the displayed HTML is updated and the URL is changed using the [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState()_method) API. Consequently, extension developers usually find that their code is "not injecting" or "run too often" even when they restrict content scripts/styles to "watch?v=" pages.

- "not injecting" occurs when you initially visit a non-watch page (e.g. the home page) and then click on a video. You would expect that the script activates on the video page because the URL has changed to "watch?v", but this does not happen because the page did not actually reload.
- "run too often" occurs when you navigate from a watch-page to a non-video page (e.g. the home page). You'd expect that the script does not run on the home page, because the URL does not match "watch?v=", but since the page did not unload, the previous scripts are still active.

> 2. Is there a better way to go about detecting video pages?

You could use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397962/chrome-extension-is-not-loading-on-browser-navigation-at-youtube/18398921#18398921) to detect these transitions and appropriately respond to these events. E.g. enable/disable your logic depending on whether the current page is a `/watch` page. This implies that you have to code carefully, and make sure that you properly clean up your DOM and events. (note that getting this right is not straightforward: merely inserting one element in the document for which you keep a reference is sufficient to prevent the garbage collector from freeing up the memory used by the whole disconnected DOM tree above!)

Comment: Rob, thank you so much for explaining and pointing me in the right direction. It is much appreciated. I definitely need to read up on "history.pushState" and the link you provided.