# Chrome extension: "content_scripts" and "Single Page Applications"

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have this in my Chrome extension `manifest.json`:

```
...

"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*.youtube.com/playlist*", "https://*.youtube.com/playlist*"],
        "css": [],
        "js": ["jquery-2.1.3.min.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
]
```

And this is `myscript.js`:

```
 console.log('Running extension code!');
```

After installing the extension, I've run two experiments:

- Experiment 1: 
  I went directly to `https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=foo` (by pasting the URL in the address bar and pressing `<ENTER>`). The console shows "Running extension code!", as expected.
- Experiment 2: 
  I went to `https://www.youtube.com` and then I manually navigated to a playlist (by clicking links), so the URL changed to `https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=foo`. The console doesn't show the message, so the extension wasn't loaded.

I guess experiment 2 fails because YouTube is a Single Page Application (SPA). In SPAs, URLs change through code events.

Questions: What is the correct way of using `content_scripts` in here? Shouldn't be Chrome responsible of matching the URL and not me? (ie: is it a bug?)

Comment: Specifically for YouTube: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397962/chrome-extension-is-not-loading-on-browser-navigation-at-youtube/18398921#18398921

Comment: Great!, exactly what I was looking for (and exactly what I wasn't able to find)