# Event Fired by YouTube When Video Page is Loaded

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am building a Firefox add-on that parses the URL when YouTube loads a video page (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tOQsswD4Tc). Using Firefox's Add-on [api for Tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs), I can't catch the event when the video page is finished loading. This might be due to YT's new asynchronous loading. Because if I hit F5, I can capture the event. I am using this code:

```
tabs.on("ready", function(tab) {
  if(tab.url.search(/youtube\.com\/watch\?v=/)!=-1){
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

I tried changing it to 'ready', 'load', 'pageshow' but nothing seems to work. How can I capture the page-load event?

Comment: Yes this is tricky youtube does something like PJAX I think. So what I did was use state progress listeners. But a more familiar way would be to insert a content script and listen to the youtube loading bar. @RobW says they are doing push state stuff though so thats interesting, but the solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397962/chrome-extension-is-not-loading-on-browser-navigation-at-youtube/18398921#18398921

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted. If you could please put this as an answer, I can accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked to solution mentions `chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated, the equivalent of that in Firefox is`onStateChange`in`nsIWebProgressListener`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWebProgressListener

The other option is to insert content script to listen to transition animation end on the youtube loading bar as also pointed out in that stack post.

[Chrome extension is not loading on browser navigation at YouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397962/chrome-extension-is-not-loading-on-browser-navigation-at-youtube/18398921#18398921)