# my chrome extension will not load untill i reload/refresh the same youtube video page again

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube

i am creating a youtube chrome extension and try to load extension from background page automatically when any youtube video or channel page open but extension will not load untill i refresh same page again. i am using chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener to fire my script. i am already given tab permission on menifest.json file here is my **background.js file is as**

function checkForValidUrl(tabId, change, tab)
{

if (change.status == 'loading' && change) {

//check for url is valid or not...and then load html through javascript

}
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);

thanks in advance.......

Answer (score 0):

Detecting hash changes should work:
[WindowEventHandlers.onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange)

I use it for checking to see if an email was opened in Gmail. Gmail also changes the URL similar to how Youtube does.

Example using your function name:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", checkForValidUrl, true);
```

Comment: Looks like Youtube uses a different method than Gmail. 

Possible duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397962/chrome-extension-is-not-loading-on-browser-navigation-at-youtube